# Marlin 2.0 Firmware temperature jumping on LCD when trying to configure UBL

Tags: marlin, prusa-i3, troubleshooting, calibration, bed-leveling

Flashed Marlin 2.0 on my Folgertech 2020 Prusa i3 variant.

Calibrating seems to have gone smoothly until I tried to set up UBL.

Saved the mesh into EEPROM with the `M500` command after a `G29 P1`.

When trying to do a test print with `G26 P10`, the temperatures for bed and hotend seem to jump (see [this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh3u6.jpg)).

*Not sure if this helps but I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONpKxkil16Q).*

Not sure what's going on here or how I can fix this. When I power cycle everything, this issue persists.

I noticed my Z probe arm's servo was buzzing. I unplugged it and the numbers stabilized. Not sure what's going on but seems like I need to stop  the power going to the servo when it's back to the 0 degree position.

Comment: Hi PGT, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Your last edit sounds like an answer, but maybe not the preferred solution... Please add a photo, from the edit we got some idea of the ABL leveling system you are using.

Comment: Hi @0scar, thanks for the response. Definitely not ideal since I want the servo to be locked in place when doing the Z-axis homing, my current solution (I will test when I get home) is to turn off the power of the servo when it gets to a specific angle. If it's not locked in place, then it might move when doing the bed levelling. Can I ask what should be in the photo?

Comment: I meant a photo of the Z-probe on the hotend carriage.